# Error Executing Query String

Tags: sql-server

Below query gives an error like:

> Invalid column name 'S'

But here `'S'` is the value of parameter `@P_APPLICABLE_TO`. Not a column.

```
@P_APPLICABLE_TO VARCHAR(20)='',

SET @QUERY = 'SELECT FSWH.ID AS ID,FSWH.REF_NO AS REFNO,FSWH.SALE AS STATUS FROM [ACCT].[SALE_HD] FSWH WHERE COMPANY_ID =' 
                        + Cast(@P_COMPANY_ID AS NVARCHAR(max)) + 'AND SALE =' + Cast(@P_APPLICABLE_TO AS NVARCHAR(max));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure it is contained in single quotes:

```
'AND SALE =' + '''' + Cast(@P_APPLICABLE_TO AS NVARCHAR(max)) + '''';
```

Use 'PRINT @QUERY' to see what the query is being set as, it is then easy to see what the problem is.